# encapsulate web service logic into other cs class

Tags: asp.net, web-services, design-patterns

I used to have asp.net web application with web service (.asmx file) inside.
The web service actually holds the logic, for example:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SomeService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public bool DoSomething(long id)
    {
        Repository rep = new Repository();
        Something fcs = rep.Get(m_User.CompanyId, id);
        return fcs.IsOk;
    }
}
```

Now I wish to put the logic code in its right project. So in MyServices project I created Some.cs file as follows:

```
public class Some
{
    public bool DoSomething(long id)
    {
        Repository rep = new Repository();
        Something fcs = rep.Get(m_User.CompanyId, id);
        return fcs.IsOk;
    }
}
```

Now I wish to recreate the .asmx file in the asp.net web application, but now I wish it use the methods in Some.cs.
I know I can do something like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SomeService : WebService
{
    private Some m_Some;
    public SomeService() {
        m_Some=new Some();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public bool DoSomething(long id)
    {
        return m_Some.DoSomething(id);
    }
}
```

But I have more then 67 methods. So I would like to know if there is a way to "connect" the Some.cs methods with the SomeService service so that the service will use the methods from Some.cs?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to "connect" the Some.cs methods to the web service apart from manually wiring them.
The way you're doing it is fine.